# Particle in the Particle swarm optimization (PSO)

Tags: algorithm, optimization, particles, particle-swarm

If I have an array **A** that consist of 50 elements, and I want to use the Particle swarm optimization (PSO) algorithm, to generate another array **B** with the same size (50 elements).

Where the value of the elements in **B** are similar or nearest to the value of elements in **A**, for example:

```
A[0]= 0.44       -----------------         B[0] = 0.40

A[1]= 0.3        -----------------         B[1] = 0.315

A[2]= 0.2        -----------------         B[2] = 0.18

A[3]= 0.08       -----------------         B[3] = 0.0684

A[4]= 0.012      -----------------         B[4] = 0.01117
```

**the new array B generated by PSO algorithm.**

In this case, does that mean each particle (candidate solution) of PSO also must consists of 50 positions and the number of dimensions is 50? Or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the short answer is that each candidate solution will also be of dimension 50.

I'm a little confused as to what function you are optimizing here but, in general, the dimensions of a given particle's location in the search space is going to match exactly the number of dimensions of a candidate solution.  That's because the *particle positions are candidate solutions*.

If **A** is a position of a particle, i.e. a possible solution to whatever function you are attempting to minimize, and the particle moves to another position **B** then that array will have the same number of dimensions as **A**.